# ESI includes in JSON response

Tags: varnish, esi

I'm struggling getting ESI includes to be replaced in a JSON context.

The following working correctly. Resulting in the ESI tag replaced by the actual contents.

```
<esi:include src="http://domain.com/esipath/" />
```

And this is not working. The ESI tag isn't replaced.

```
{
    "test": "<esi:include src="http://domain.com/esipath/" />"
}
```

I have found some resources on google and a possible solution seems to set `esi_syntax` to 0x3 for varnish to skip checking for valid XML.
This doesn't seem to work on Varnish 4. When I start the deamon with the runtime param I get the following error.

```
 Error: Unknown parameter "esi_syntax".
```

Is this setting deprecated in Varnish 4?

Any ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

indeed that parameter is depricated in varnish4. What you have to do is to activate the feature `ESI_DISABLE_XML_CHECK`.

For me I edit `/etc/default/varnish` (debian based system) and add

```
-p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check
```

to the `DEAMON_OPTS` parameters, for example:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,4GB \
             -p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check"
```

Comment: Also thanks for your answer! The answer of regilero has pointed me in the right direction. I'll mark you answer as accepted because it is most complete. The bounty is for regilero because he was first to answer.

Answer (score 2):

On [this diff](https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-commit/2013-September/009941.html) we can see the removal of `esi_syntax`, and the new `esi_disable_xml_check` feature coming in for `0x3` old value.

I also found a reference on `esi_disable_xml_check` on [the man](http://manned.org/varnishd/53bcf0f2).

Comment: Thanks very much. It is working now. Enabled the feature and the esi's were loading right away. I have another problem now because my esi is returning html which I put inside a JSON attribute, but this is causing syntax errors because of the unescaped html. Not sure how to escape the html yet. Have to do it on the webserver, in my app or in varnish some way.

Comment: IMHO you should use an esi url with a specified format and that format should ask for json escaped content (done on server side).

Comment: Yup, that's how I implemented it. http://myhost.com/esi/?jsonEncode=true. Everything is working perfect now.